# White spaces in clipping mask of just gradient and compound mask?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, gradient, clipping-mask

[image: White spaces in clipping mask of just gradient and compound mask]

How do I take these annoying spaces away? I thought it was a preview error. But I moved it and it stayed in the exact same place.

Comment: Those white triangular areas limited by green layer registration color curve and magenta areas should obviously be something else. Unfortunately we cannot here see what shapes, layers, effects, blending modes etc etc are used. You should repeat the problem in much simpler case that can be totally shown in screeshots or you should give a link to the file in some cloud which do not want login.  Otherwise you can get only guesses, or  nothing, except downvotes and closure.

Comment: Is this Illustrator?

Comment: This is illustrator, yes. Those are all the layers. All normal blend modes. File is for corporate work unfortunately. So ownership of the open file is an issue. Sorry. If someone can tell me if they have ever experienced this? And how to fix this?